# Abigail from Murdered Soul Suspect

Tags: murdered-soul-suspect

I have just played *Murdered: Soul Suspect*. And if you have played until the end, you'll see that

> Abigail possesses a person, uses the person to kill another person, and after this, she possesses another person to kill the ex-murderer.

But if she does this, she always have to possess another person, until everyone is dead, so I sincerely think that are some mistakes in the history.
Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine she either uses the same body that kills her next Medium to kill her previous killer, or possibly manipulates their deaths to look like accodents, suicide and natural causes (she might even let the Capital Punishment do the work for her if her bodies are ever caught).

She doesn't have to kill her puppets immediately after using them, since Ronan and Baxter were killed on the same night despite being involved in different killings days (if not months) apart.